# php equivalent to window.location.replace()

Tags: php, redirect

so I have this particular code in a website that I am building:

```
<?php
    session_start();
    session_destroy();
    header("Location: login.php");
?>
```

what it does is basically destroy the content of $_SESSION and redirect the user to login.php
the thing is the user can still use the browser's back button and go back to the previous page.

I would like to use a php function that works in a similar way to window.location.replace() as in it removes the previous url from the history after redirecting.

for more precision it is because the main page receive its essential data (username, password) from a form submitted with the post method. so if the user clicks on logout, and then goes back to the main page, it will only ask to resend the data then it will reload the page, which it should not do.

Comment: PHP is a server-side language meaning that you have _no control_ over the user's browser. That means you cannot control their history. You could write an if statement in PHP that renders some JavaScript that writes `window.location.replace`. Other than that you cannot do anything with PHP.

Comment: It's a little hard to ascertain what your specific problem is from your question.  If you are truly wanting to clear the history so that the "Back" button no longer returns you to the previous page then that needs to be done using JS as justCarty stated.  If the problem is that after logging out the user can then access a page which previously they had accessed but no longer should be able to that is generally handled on the server side by sniffing the login state and redirecting the user to a different page.  Is it one of these two?  Or something else?

Comment: @JcNolan my problem is that after logging out, the user can still click on back and it will resubmit their login data since I am using post. As  a solution I tried to look for a way to remove the url from the history so the user won't be able to go back to it, but since I cannot do it in php I will have to look for another solution, I will try sniffing the login state as you suggested thank you.

Comment: Yes, sorry I can't be of more help but I'm not at my main PHP system currently.  But the problem you're describing is not something I've ever had to deal with, so perhaps I've used different patterns previously which avoided the issue? Been awhile since I've coded a login from scratch.  Here's a good article on the specifics of good coding practices for avoiding various issues which might be of help. https://www.wikihow.com/Create-a-Secure-Login-Script-in-PHP-and-MySQL

Comment: I don't understand why it's a problem, won't they just log in again which they're allowed to do? Or you set a session called "loginfailed" in the login script (or something less obvious) and if they hit back and the session exists it just redirects them to the homepage/required page and doesn't submit the form

Comment: Can you post the rest of your code, how you are logging in, where they are going and where the logout button is etc? As JC Nolan said it's not a problem that I've had to solve so I think there might be something else in your set up that's causing the problem

Comment: @JcNolan and JustCarty thank you guys for redirecting me. What I did was redirect the form submission to another page on which I passed the data into a session, (luckily for me session is an array!) then redirects to the main page. Now in my main page I just verifies if isset(_$SESSION) and if not it redirects to the login. Since the logout button clears the session whenever someone clicks on back after the logout, they will be redirected to the login page